# Why second ADDTIME function in MySql gives wrong result?

Tags: mysql

I try to use ADDTIME in MySQL 5.7. The complete code and results are as below. The key steps:
I create a table and fill it with three dates.
Select the dates and the calculated next days. It works.
Make a view with the same select and use that. It still works.
Repeat almost the same SELECT as above, but this time not on the original table, but on the view. Instead of calculating the next day from d2 (i.e. d + 1 day), what should be d + 2 days, it calculates the ADDTIME from the current date.
Could you explain why it works like this (or is it a bug?)? It is not because I use a view in between, because if the last SELECT I use d from v1, not d2, then it still works correctly.

Thanks,

```
mysql> create table testdates (d DATE);  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into testdates (d) VALUES ("2020-01-01"), ("2021-02-02"), ("2022-03-03");  
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select d, CAST(ADDTIME(d, "24:00:00") AS DATE) from testdates;  
+------------+--------------------------------------+  
| d          | CAST(ADDTIME(d, "24:00:00") AS DATE) |  
+------------+--------------------------------------+  
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02                           |  
| 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-03                           |  
| 2022-03-03 | 2022-03-04                           |  
+------------+--------------------------------------+  
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql> create view v1 as select d, CAST(ADDTIME(d, "24:00:00") AS DATE) d2 from testdates;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from v1;
+------------+------------+
| d          | d2         |
+------------+------------+
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 |
| 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-03 |
| 2022-03-03 | 2022-03-04 |
+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select d, d2, CAST(ADDTIME(d2, "24:00:00") AS DATE) from v1;
+------------+------------+---------------------------------------+
| d          | d2         | CAST(ADDTIME(d2, "24:00:00") AS DATE) |
+------------+------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-02 | 2023-04-18                            |
| 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-03 | 2023-04-18                            |
| 2022-03-03 | 2022-03-04 | 2023-04-18                            |
+------------+------------+---------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if you remove `CAST ... AS DATE` you'll see that `ADDTIME(d2, "24:00:00")` is returning just the time `24:00:00`, not a full datetime.

Comment: And this simplified code: `select CAST(ADDTIME(CAST(ADDTIME('2020-01-01', "24:00:00") AS DATE), "24:00:00") AS DATE);`

Comment: don't use addtime to add a day, just add a day?  https://dbfiddle.uk/_nmkesl7

Comment: @ysth:I actually add a non-full day, this is why the ADDTIME. It was just the simplest working example. In my real problem, d is a datetime and I add 18 hours and round it to a day. As in my current problem the second rounding is a full day, so your solution is still a great help.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 had a bug that ADDTIME() returns a `VARCHAR`, not a `DATETIME`.  See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76355

Here's a demo dbfiddle that captures the result of the query as a new table, and shows that the data type returned by ADDTIME() is `VARCHAR(29)`.

https://dbfiddle.uk/KnWYuhox

According to the bug report, this was not the case in earlier versions of MySQL, and as I test MySQL 8.0, it is fixed again (though the bug report has not been closed).

Comment: I had noticed that it was not a datetime, this is why I did the CAST and thought that that will do the trick. I still do not get, why CAST (... AS DATE) does not work.

Comment: The string value included only a _time_, not a datetime. So it has to assume a date, and it picked the current date.

Comment: I do not get it. d2 has the date part in it (actually only the date part) and when it adds only a time, it cannot be that it picked a date for the time as well, because then the sum of the two would be a much higher date not the current date. It seems that it ONLY took the current date and dropped the date part of d2, what was there before.

Comment: Hence it is a bug, and one that has been fixed in MySQL 8.0. The chances of it being fixed in 5.7 is zero.

Comment: @jollytall As I mentioned in a comment, the nested `ADDTIME()` is just returning the time, without the date. So that must be part of the bug.